# wkhtmltopdf works for some sites but not others

Tags: html, css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I don't understand why wkhtmltopdf is causing problems for me. I'm hoping someone has some ideas.

I have an HTML file with a lot of css references to assets I have. **All of these CSS refrences are absolute paths**. I know this for sure as I've downloaded the html file in tmp/ that wkhtmltopdf generated to my computer and viewed it - the styling appears perfectly.

But the PDF generated has no styling at all.

If I try creating a pdf of a site like http://www.google.com it works perfectly though.

So I tried moving my HTML file (the one generated in tmp/) to another website on another domain. And then I tried creating a PDF of it on the command line with wkhtmltopdf... again, no styling came through at all.

This makes no sense to me.

Does wkhtmltopdf maintain a cache? If so, how do I clear this cache?

ANY ideas welcome, because I'm out of them.

**EDIT**

I just tried creating a PDF on my local Windows PC by pointing to the URL mentioned above (when I moved the html file to another website on another domain), and locally the PDF is generated perfectly. It just seems to be a problem generating it on my remote server.

Comment: A while back I had a PHP application use wkhtmltopdf to convert HTML to PDF, I was replacing absolute URIs to the full URL.  For example: `src="/` and `href="/` with `src="http://domain.com/` and `href="http://domain.com/`.  This was unique in that I was converting parts of a HTML document on the server and not a .html file, so it may be different in your case.

Comment: Yeah, back when I started developing this program I noticed I had to use the full path like `http://domain.com/whatever.css` whenever I reference css files. So they are all like that on my page as well. I have made an edit to the above message, if it provides any insight. Surely it has to be some sort of caching problem?

Comment: `wget http://domain.com/whatever.css && cat whatever.css` from the server/shell to make sure the server can access itself correctly using your external URL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that, and it does appear to be accessing the contents of the file correctly. I did notice the version of wkhtmltopdf is quite old (0.9.9), maybe this is a problem. I installed it by following these instructions: http://fedir.github.io/web/blog/2013/09/25/install-wkhtmltopdf-on-ubuntu/ - do you know how I can update wkhtmltopdf to the latest version? Thanks

Comment: About a year ago, 0.9.9 was better than later versions due to it being able to render SVG IIRC.  You could try building it from source, or finding another binary.  I remember not being able to resolve the SVG problem by building the latest version by source, I was using 0.9.9 as well.

Comment: I ended up fixing the problem by upgrading to the latest version (0.12.1). Thanks.